# Why can't I read from /proc in Java using Commons IO FileUtils, but can do so using a plain FileInputStream?

Tags: java, linux, apache-commons-io

I had a problem with reading `/proc/%d/stat` files using my Java method copyFiles() (source code below).
I have found workaround using similar readProc() method.

Now I am wondering what was the problem. Output files were created, but each file had 0 bytes (in /proc/ all files are 0 bytes because it is not standard filesystem). FileUtils is from the Apache Commons IO library.

I've tried to do the same using java.nio - again, IOException is being thrown that attributes are wrong for each file.

I removed some part of the code regarding parsing exceptions etc.

Why does this work with FileInputStream, but not with `FileUtils.copyFile()`?

```
public void copyFiles() {
    final File dir = new File("/proc");
    final String[] filedirArray = dir.list();
    long counter = 0;
    for(String filedir : filedirArray) {
            final File checkFile = new File(dir, filedir);
            if (checkFile.isDirectory()) {
                    try {
                            Integer.parseInt(filedir);
                            File srcFile = new File(checkFile, "stat");
                            File dstFile = new File("/home/waldekm/files/stat" + "." + Long.toString(counter++));
                            try {                                    
                                FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile, dstFile);
                            } catch (IOException e1) {}
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                            // not a number, do nothing
                    }                        
            }
    }
}

public static void readProc(final String src, final String dst) {
    FileInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;

    File srcFile = new File(src);
    File dstFile = new File(dst);

    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(srcFile);
        out = new FileOutputStream(dstFile);
        int c;
        while((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(c);
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
 }  finally {

        try {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {}
        try {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {}
    }
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `android`? Your code won't work on Android, as it refers to directories that do not exist.

Comment: Actually, it is from the android project. Directory name is just an example.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is most likely that the operating system is reporting the file size as zero.

On my machine, `man 2 stat` says this:

> "*For most files under the `/proc` directory, `stat()` does  not  return  the file  size in the `st_size` field; instead the field is returned with the value 0.*"

(The `stat` system call will be what the JVM uses to find out what a file's size is.)

Comment: you if i just open any proc file in java and try to read using .read() method then it will not work? right...in may case .read gives -1 and in kernel space proc read doesnt execuatate

Comment: @Mr.32 - No.  That's not what we are talking about.  We are talking about what `stat` reports as the file size.  If a process has the relevant privilege then it should have no problem *reading* from `/proc`.  (Try running the program as root ...)

Comment: i have given 666 to that /proc file so that should not be problem

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881744/linux-file-permission ... about why you can't access /proc/... files even though the "mode" says you should be able to.

Comment: Nope. `FileInputStream.read()` doesn't use `stat()` to determine end of stream. It uses a C `read()` returning zero.

Comment: @user207421 that’s the point. That’s why copying using just `FileInputStream.read()` works (because it doesn’t care whether `stat()` reports a zero size). Whereas the most likely reason `FileUtils.copyFile()` does not work (or did not work back then when the question was asked) is/was that it does check the file size upfront, to optimize the operation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snipped that would read specific fields from a proc file, using methods that are available (but not documented directly) in the Process class of Android. Modify the FORMAT  buffer and the output buffer size to read more/different values from the proc file,

```
int PROC_SPACE_TERM = (int)' ';
int PROC_OUT_LONG = 0x2000

public static final int[] PROCESS_STATS_FORMAT = new int[] {
    PROC_SPACE_TERM,
    PROC_SPACE_TERM,
    PROC_SPACE_TERM,
    PROC_SPACE_TERM,
    PROC_SPACE_TERM,
    PROC_SPACE_TERM,
    PROC_SPACE_TERM,
    PROC_SPACE_TERM,
    PROC_SPACE_TERM,
    PROC_SPACE_TERM,
    PROC_SPACE_TERM,
    PROC_SPACE_TERM,
    PROC_SPACE_TERM,
    PROC_SPACE_TERM|PROC_OUT_LONG,                  // 13: utime
    PROC_SPACE_TERM|PROC_OUT_LONG                   // 14: stime
};

long buf[] = new long[2];

try {
    int pid = 1000; // Assume 1000 is a valid pid for a process. 
    Method mReadProcFile = 
              Process.class.getMethod("readProcFile", String.class,
                                      int[].class, String[].class,   
                                      long[].class, float[].class);
    mReadProcFile.invoke(null, "/proc/" + pid + "/stat", 
                         PROCESS_STATS_FORMAT, null, buf, null);

    return buf;

} catch(NoSuchMethodException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error! Could not get access to JNI method - readProcFile");
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
Log.e(TAG, "Error! Could not invoke JNI method - readProcFile");
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error! Illegal access while invoking JNI method - readProcFile");
}

return null;
```

Answer (score -1):

I see you are creating a FileInputStream to read a /proc file.  Instead I suggest you create a FileReader object.  FileInputStream gets tripped up by the lack of file length for /proc files but FileReader does not.

Comment: 'Gets tripped up' how? `FileReader` uses `FileInputStream` under the hood, so what you describe is impossible, and your proposed solution changes nothing.